# Is the 2010 Landsat world map (GLS 2010) available in a GoogleMaps browser?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, landsat

Is the 2010 Landsat world map, also known as GLS 2010, available to view anywhere on the internet in a GoogleMaps browser?

I need to find it so that it can be added as a layer to a GoogleMaps interface on a wiki site Im helping out on.

It has much more up-to-date coverage in remote locations than Bing and Google, even though the resolution isnt so good.

Comment: If you enable Earth mode (Google Earth) you can use the KMZ http://imagery.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/LandsatGLS/TM_Multispectral/ImageServer/kml/mapImage.kmz

Comment: I dont think Landsat images are on any map server for displaying. You can download the images, and host them on your own server.